# Compare Audio Element to Class

Tags: javascript

Below I have a case scenarion when an audio element has not been loaded.
How can I detect if audio2 is not of type `<audio preload......`

```
console.log(audio)
console.log(audio2) 


<audio preload="auto" src=""></audio>  <----- Console Response to audio


Class {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, _dispatchInstances: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, _dispatchListeners: ƒ, …}   

^^^ console response to audio2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (audio !== null) {
  if (audio.src === undefined) {
    console.log("no audio src");
  } else {
    console.log(audio.src);
    audio.pause();
  }
}
```

Using Google Chrome this worked for me.
Not sure if undefined will always be true for other browsers. 
Please provide a better answer if you know.